# Corba communication between different languages

Tags: corba, idl, iiop

How is the CORBA IDL used to support communication between objects that have been implemented in different languages?

Comment: You can think CORBA IDL objects as valuetypes or structs (in some languages).
Which CORBA implementation needs to implement [Marshal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29) and Unmarshal that is responsable from transform message data to classes.

Answer (score 3):

CORBA IDL lets you specify objects interface in programming language neutral way. Once that is accomplished for objects you would like to expose over the wire, CORBA specification details how is that interface exposed, and used in different languages like C++, Smalltalk, Java, etc.. This part of the specification is referred to as "language mappings".

So it is not that all of your python objects just appear as java objects on the other side. You need to describe behavior of object you would like to share with IDL, and than code them, and their usage according to the rules specified by the language mapping.